# FATAL: unexpected error when reading kubeadm-config ConfigMap: ClusterConfiguration key value pair missing

Tags: kubernetes

When running a `kubeadm upgrade plan` I am getting:

`[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
[upgrade] Making sure the cluster is healthy:
[upgrade/config] Making sure the configuration is correct:
[upgrade/config] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[upgrade/config] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[upgrade/config] FATAL: unexpected error when reading kubeadm-config ConfigMap: ClusterConfiguration key value pair missing`

What is this configmap and how do I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message comes from the `kubeadm` 1.13 binary. When doing a `kubeadm upgrade` 1.10 -> 1.11, ensure you are using the `kubeadm` 1.11 binary. Similarliy, use the `kubeadm` 1.12 binary when going from 1.11 -> 1.12.